# Javascript event refuses to die

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have a page which has two different event listeners picking up click events from inside the page. One listener is generic to the site, the other is specific to the page. Recently, a link was added which runs through the first handler, which processes it, opens the url in a new window and then stops the event. The problem is, the second handler then executes, stops the event again and somehow the event continues and executes.

I have stopPropagation, and cancelBubble both executing on this event. When it arrives at the second handler, it has a prevented field which is set to true, but still it carries on. The only way to stop it is to put a check in the second handler which skips its code if the event arrives with prevented set to true.

My question is, why would this happen at all? Why is stopPropagation not working? This happens in all browsers, BTW.

Comment: Is it possible that your second listener isnt 'listening' yet when the first one fires and subsequently calls stopProp?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you try to stop event from firing on the same element. Have you tried to use stopImmediatePropagation method?

Answer (score 0):

As Samuel Liew correctly commented, adding `return false;` to the end of your first event handler might do the trick. This is because some browsers ignore the `.stopPropagation()` (However, others will ignore the return)

Comment: You are doing something wrong or this is a bug in jQuery. I bet on the first.

Comment: @bjornd Are you sure this is to me? There's no mention of jQuery in the question and I'm not the asker of the question, simply trying to offer a solution